# Keep setTimeout function running after browser becomes idle

Tags: javascript

The following code is used for keeping track of updates from a database.

Problem is it will stop running after some time (probably when the browser becomes idle).

```
$(function() {
    function Update() {
        var postData = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/ajax_api.php?dashboarddata',
            type : 'post',
            data: postData,                
            success: function(resp) {
                $('#entradasmas7').html($('#entradasmas7' , resp).html());
                $('#entradasmenos7').html($('#entradasmenos7' , resp).html());

                // Call Update again after 30 seconds.
                setTimeout(function() { Update(); }, 30000);                    
            }
        });
    }

    // Call postData the first time to start it off.
    Update();
});
```

How can I make it run continually regardless of browser state, or call it back when the window becomes active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of error it will not restart the timer, so there are 2 solution:

A.: add error handler and put the `setTimeout(function() { Update(); }, 30000);` code into the handler, because in case of error nothing restarts the timer.

disadvantages: callings are not exact 30sec later in case of long time response

```
$(function() {
    function Update() {
        var postData = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/ajax_api.php?dashboarddata',
            type : 'post',
            data: postData,                
            success: function(resp) {
                $('#entradasmas7').html($('#entradasmas7' , resp).html());
                $('#entradasmenos7').html($('#entradasmenos7' , resp).html());

                // Call Update again after 30 seconds.
                setTimeout(function() { Update(); }, 30000);                    
            }, 
            error: function() {
                setTimeout(function() { Update(); }, 30000);
            }
        });
    }

    // Call postData the first time to start it off.
    Update();
});
```

B.: use setInterval instead of setTimer: but you have to schedule only onece, and you have to abort the previous ajax call if the next tick is coming:

```
$(function() {
  var xhr = null;
  function Update() {
    var postData = "";
    if(xhr!=null) { xhr.abort(); } // avoid paralell call of ajax_api.php, so we stop the previous one
    xhr = $.ajax({
      url: 'functions/ajax_api.php?dashboarddata',
      type : 'post',
      data: postData,                
      success: function(resp) {
        $('#entradasmas7').html($('#entradasmas7' , resp).html());
        $('#entradasmenos7').html($('#entradasmenos7' , resp).html());
      }
    });
  }
  // Call postData the first time to start it off.
  Update();
  setInterval(function() { Update(); }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: You can simplify #1 solution: write `setTimeout()` only once, in `complete:` branch.

Comment: As of Jquery 1.5 complete is also called by jquery in case of success or error

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean: for me, just because `complete:` happens in any case, it's the right place to put the unique `setTimeout()` statement.

Comment: there are two cases: error or success. It is nice if you write setTimeout code once in complete callback function.